# Can I use recolor artwork feature in Ai to get this result (swap color of objects)?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, color-spaces

See the image below. I need to do this thing. If you see, the positions of hands and diamonds are same in both parts, but there colors are swapped. I did this manually by picking each of them and moving here and there.

But I faced a problem with this. 1st it's really time consuming. Secondly, the final height and width of whole group (*Highlighted by red boxes*) becomes slightly different. I need same position of each individual object and whole group, so that they can be placed on over other exactly.

So I learned about recolor artwork feature. But I couldn't figure it how to use it and if it's even possible.

**Can it be done with recolor artwork keeping the same colors but swapped? If yes, I would like to know how.**

NOTE: Each individual object is a vector. There are many objects in each object with different shades of same color. (See image 2)

[image: Image 1]
[image: Image 2]

Comment: @Scott I would like to hear your views about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My first recommendation is to clean up your file, you are using **24 different colors** for three simple objects with the same color and different tonal values.

With this, you can always use different Symbols and replace them.

In this example there are just two colors and the illustration is made duplicating symbols:

[image]

Then, copy just two symbols and edit the colors to change them. Once done, paste the original symbols. Copy two of the new color symbols and repeat the process:

[image]

You will have all the symbols the same color but a symbol library to replace them: select a symbol at the illustration, a symbol at the **Symbols Panel** and from the **Symbols Panel Menu** choose > **Replace Symbol**

[image: Library]

[image: replace symbol]

Comment: This is a nice approach. But currently I would like to solve it with edit color feature as it is a new experience.

Comment: Meanwhile, one off topic question: Could you please tell what can I do with my 2-3 questions that have got -ve points? I get a warning that you might be blocked. Can I fix them somehow?

Comment: I'm sorry but I think I can not help you, two of your questions with negative votes are from February and September, I'm a GD.SE user since October, 18.

Comment: I understand. Where can I ask about it on stackexchange?

Comment: You can make a search at [Meta](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions). If you don't find any answer, you can make your own question there.

Answer (score 6):

You got most of the way there, you just need to group similar colors to speed up the process (so that you don't have to select and recolor each and every color manually).

---

Select everything and open the **Recolor Artwork** panel.

Now change **Color** from *Auto* to the number of color groups in your artwork.

This will group similar colors together when changing. (In your case all the colors of each object are similar, I would choose 3 color groups.)

[image: example]

---

It may not do a great job automatically grouping everything. You can always shift around the colors between groups:

[image: move colors between groups]

Comment: Hi, since I find this feature a bit hard to understand, could you please add a little more explanation?

Comment: Sure, once you have *Recolor Artwork* opened up you want to change **Colors** to 4 (3 groups + white), now it should do this automatically, but if it doesn't group your colors correctly rearrange them manually.

Comment: In the **New** column, double click on the (new) color and change it to the desired color range - this will apply the same color change to all of the other colors in the group (relative to how they were - kinda like adjusting the hue). Make sure to select **Recolor Artwork** or it won't apply any of the changes.

Comment: Okay I got your first point. Now I see 3 groups and white. It grouped them perfectly as you said. Now, once I grouped (didn't do anything else yet) the objects didn't change the color, but they became a little lighter. Is it because the "primary color" (the color which we choose under **New** by double clicking) is light?

Comment: Probably, can you upload the file and share it here? I would love to take a look.

Comment: To check this, I made it same as the darkest color of the group, objects became of normal color, just like beginning. It almost made the colors same as original. But there was some difference. So how can I fix it. I understand how can I swap color, but can't make it exactly of same color. I guess it has something to do with HUE or saturation.

Comment: Yes sharing now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87761/discussion-between-vikas-kumar-and-welz).